# Recommended video players for Android SDK that support Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast

We are developing a native Android native app and are considering our options when it comes to video players (JW Player, .etc). Does anyone know of a video player for Android SDK that supports Chromecast? I have seen players that support HLS, etc but not Chromecast as of yet. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to enable casting for your application, I would use the CastCompanionLibrary located here:

https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

Using this will allow you to cast videos from your app. As far as playing media within the app itself use the MediaPlayer view and add a custom button for chromecast if one is detected.